# Shorten a url with params

Tags: angular

I have a url with params so that users can share the url and it'll bring up specific content associated with the params. I'm just wondering if the url can be somehow shortened when sharing it?

This is my url (as a comment so you can see it without scrolling):

> http://localhost:3000/#/find;categories=m-African,m-Argentine,m-Asian,m-Asian
>   Fusion,m-BBQ,m-Bakery,m-Beverages,m-Brazilian,m-Breakfast,m-British,m-Cafe,m-Cambodian,m-Chinese,m-Coffee and Tea,m-Contemporary,m-Continental,m-Deli,m-Desserts,m-Drinks
>   Only,m-European,m-Fijian,m-Filipino,m-Finger Food,m-Fish and
>   Chips,m-French Fusion,m-German,m-Greek,m-Grill,m-Healthy Food,m-Ice
>   Cream,m-Indian,m-Indonesian,m-International,m-Irish,m-Italian,m-Japanese,m-Jewish,m-Juices,m-Kiwi,m-Korean,m-Latin,m-American,m-Lebanese,m-Malaysian,m-Mediterranean,m-Mexican,m-Middle
>   Eastern,m-Mongolian,m-Moroccan,m-Nepalese,m-North
>   Indian,m-Pacific,m-Persian,m-Pizza,m-Portuguese,m-Pub
>   Food,m-Seafood,m-Singaporean,m-South Indian,m-Spanish,m-Sri
>   Lankan,m-Steakhouse,m-Street
>   Food,m-Sushi,m-Taiwanese,m-Thai,m-Turkish,m-Vietnamese,gp-meat,gp-dairy,gp-confectionary,gp-dessert,gp-baking,gp-condiments,gp-beverages,gp-Dr
>   IQ,gp-Magma,gp-Tornado;mealtypes=dine in,take
>   away,delivery;location=Greymouth, New
>   Zealand;distancenumber=15;distanceunits=kilometers

Or is it actually good practice to just share url's this long anyway?

Comment: have you fond a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on you how you want to achieve this thing. But personally I feel Long URLs are not good to share because of:-

- Very hard to understand/recognize
- Some parameters can be missed while copy paste this URL (which may cause break in functionality)

  - Not good to human eye :)

I would Create a tiny URL with this URL and share that tiny URL to users and parse it on my App. [Refer this](http://tinyurl.com/)